# Can a forEach lambda result in a race condition?

Tags: java, lambda, thread-safety

I am unsure of how lambdas work in practice, and I am concerned since under certain circumstances, lambdas can result in errors such as ConcurrentModificationExceptions if you use them incorrectly, which seems to be indicative of a race condition.
Consider the code below.

```
private class deltaCalculator{
    Double valueA;
    Double valueB;

    //Init delta
    volatile Double valueDelta = null;

    private void calculateMinimum(List<T> dataSource){
        dataSource.forEach((entry -> {
            valueA = entry.getA();
            valueB = entry.getB();
            Double dummyDelta;

            dummyDelta = Math.abs(valueA - valueB);

            if(valueDelta == null){
                setDelta(dummyDelta);
            }else {
                setDelta((valueDelta > dummyDelta) ? dummyDelta : valueDelta);
            }
        }));
    }

    private void setDelta(Double d){
        this.valueDelta = d;
    }
}
```

How does the forEach loop operate? Do different calls get passed to different threads where the JVM considers it appropriate, opening up the possibility of a race condition that could lead to incorrect minimum calculation?
If not, why can a forEach lambda throw a ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: I can't see what could be causing the ConcurrentModificationException , are you sure there's not another place where you modify the same `List<T> dataSource` object?

Comment: I didn't mean you could get a CME in this case, but if you attempt something such as removing an element from a Collection while in the forEach, the CME is thrown.

Comment: Ah, ok. +1 to berry120 answer then. No multithreading is involved here, the lambda is called synchronously as long as you're not using stuff like `list.parallelStream().forEach` - but what can be misleading is that we generally (sometimes wrongly) associate the word "concurrent" with multithreading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get a ConcurrentModificationException if you try to modify the collection that you're iterating over while the for each loop runs. This could be done in a separate thread entirely, but much more commonly occurs when you try to modify the collection in the loop body.

> Do different calls get passed to different threads where the JVM considers it appropriate, opening up the possibility of a race condition that could lead to incorrect minimum calculation?

No. No multithreading is taking place in your example above.

Comment: If multithreading is occurring, that means the function is unsafe and we cannot guarantee that it would always find the minimum difference, correct?

Comment: If *unsafe* multithreading is occurring that affects the relevant fields above in a separate thread, then you cannot guarantee that it will always be correct. That's not specific to lambdas or for each loops, that's the case for any method executing on any object. However, that will never happen "in the background" - it will only be as a result of specific, unsafe multithreaded code that you have written. (The JVM never makes unsafe multithreaded optimisations in this way, it'd be a nightmare if it did.)