# Is this code threadsafe, using Java 8 Lambdas - stream.forEach

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, race-condition

Assume that I have a list of book elements:  `List<Book> libraryBooks` and the following code:

```
List<BookAuthor> authors = new ArrayList<>();
libraryBooks.stream().forEach(e -> {
                                     authors.add(createAuthor(e));
                                   });
```

I've looked around and found similar questions, (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039887/can-a-foreach-lambda-result-in-a-race-condition)) but I'm not yet convinced.  Because I've been reading a book on the subject and the book seems to indicate that the above could introduce race conditions if the stream was run in parallel - but I'm not using a parallel stream, so is the above subject to race conditions?  Or is the book wrong/misleading?

Here's the excerpt from the book that I'm referring to:
[image]

Comment: "that the above could introduce race conditions if the stream was run in parallel" - It doesn't have to be a parallel stream for it to not be thread-safe. Any other thread could attempt to modify `authors` while you're adding elements to it inside the `forEach`.

Comment: I'm sure your book shows the correct, idiomatic way of doing what you want. Why not use that idiomatic way?

Comment: The above example that I posted is actually a very simple example, but I'm looking at some code in an existing application which actually does something more complex (ie, using a builder to create an object) and then adding that new object to the list, but same idea as the above example that i posted.  I'm just wondering if that could cause race conditions?

Comment: @Nena the good practice with streams is to write code that is parallelizable. In general, one should be able to replace `stream()` by `parallelStream()` and still have correct code. It's not the case with what you have there, since ArrayList is not thread-safe and would be modified from concurrent threads. That's what the book says: you should write *parallel-ready* code. If it's sequential, it doesn't have any race condition, since there is no race. But it's not parallel-ready, because it would have a race condition if it as made parallel.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to create a new list of items by applying a function to each of the elements, then `map` is the function you should use. This is how you should write it:

```
List<BookAuthor> authors = libraryBooks.stream()
            .map(e -> createAuthor(e))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you explain in what way this answers OP's question? I understand that this is the proper way to build a `List` with streams in general, but how does it answer the question of thread safety?